Css to make a folder like structure
How can I make the slanting line as to make the folder like structure
html
<body>
    <div class="sample-div">
        <div class="sample-support-div">
        </div>
        Sample
    </div>
</body>

css
.sample-div{
    border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
    border-top: none;
    min-height: 139px;
    min-width: 248px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.sample-div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:50%;
    border-top: 1px solid lightslategrey;
  }

.sample-support-div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: -1px;
    border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
    border-bottom: none;
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 124px;
    border-radius: 30px 100px 0 0;
}

How can I make the slanting line as to make the folder like structure
Made so far
Required design
